# Can I parse uri from resource?

Tags: android, uri

```
// startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.donate_url))));
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
```

When I use the first,app will crash in emulator but the second run well, how can I fix the first?

Comment: Let the crash occur to get some feedback of the problem, check log cat for details.

Answer (score 0):

both the lines are working fine..
tested in 2.1 emulator...
with the donate_url= "http://www.google.com"

there must be problem with the url you are using...

check log cat as **Pentium10** said.